# Arduino and Android for home automation

Tags: android, arduino, android-wifi

I am planning to use Arduino and Android Smart phone for home automation. I have already built an Android app. The Android app is ready to communicate via WiFi. The important point is there is no communication via Internet - the communication is only like this:

- Android --> WiFi --> Arduino
- Arduino --> WiFi --> Android

Can I get guidance for the activities mentioned below?

I am using WiFly Shield for WiFi communication. Can any one point me to the sample code where the Arduino interacts with Android? Is there is any way to ping Android from Anduino?

Comment: See if this helps http://www.buildcircuit.com/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-arduino/

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I am looking for similar kind of code with WIFI setup. Could you please point me to such an example ?

Comment: http://dangerousprototypes.com/2011/01/05/android-phone-controls-arduino-over-wifi/

Comment: So far, I dont find any working sample codes available. I planned to write a code from scratch. Meantime I will check for updates from you people as well..

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Ethernet server in Arduino (available as an example sketch) and then in the Android you can make simple HTTP requests.

In the Android side, you can have code something like below, where you can open the Arduino url using HTTP

```
URL url = new URL(arduinoCommandURl);
InputStream is = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
is.read();
```

Also checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832481/how-to-create-an-android-app-to-control-arduino-over-wi-fi).